# Can't build readline when trying to install Python 2.6.5 in Debian 4.3.2

Tags: python, linux, debian, readline

I am trying to install Python 2.6.5 on my web server running Debian 4.3.2.1-1. I unpacked the tarball, ran "./configure --prefix /usr/", then ran "make". I saw this message.

```
Failed to find the necessary bits to build these modules:
_bsddb             _hashlib           _ssl            
_tkinter           bsddb185           bz2             
dl                 imageop            readline        
sunaudiodev                                           
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```

I thought it was not a big deal, so I went ahead with the rest of the installation, which I think was just running "make install" as root.

I tried running the new version of Python, and it worked, but some things acted funny. The usual keyboard shortcuts at the interactive prompt didn't work. I tried importing readline and the interpreter couldn't find it. Is there any way to make it work? I tried looking in setup.py like "make" told me, but I couldn't find any clues that were useful to me. I would really like to get readline to work. I don't really care about the other modules.

**EDIT:** This is on a DreamHost private server. They have some older versions of Python with readline, and they seem to work fine. I am trying to make it work with this new version.

I would like to add that I am kind of a Linux newbie, and I don't know much about installing packages, and using RPM or apt-get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll probably need to install the [libreadline-dev](http://packages.debian.org/etch/libreadline-dev) virtual package for Debian 4 (`etch`) to be able to build python with `libreadline` support.  Check the package dependencies for the Debian python2.6 source package [here](http://packages.debian.org/source/squeeze/python2.6).  It's for a newer version of Debian so not all of the same versions will be available in `etch` but you should be able to hunt down the closest versions available there to be able to build most of the other missing modules.  Or you could try a dry run of installing the current testing (`squeeze`) version of python2.6 and see how many dependencies it brings along and if you're OK with upgrading those on your system.

Comment: I tried that and it worked. Thank you. In case anyone needs to know, I installed libreadline-dev by running the command "aptitude install libreadline-dev" as root.

Comment: +1 for the link to python source package dependencies - even works for me struggling with the same issue for Python 2.7 on Debian 6

Comment: In case anyone else runs into my situation: If you ever need to build Python 2.6.6+ on Ubuntu 14.04, which has readline 6.3, you may run into a build error because of changes to readline.  In such a situation, I was able to resolve the build error by applying the patch for Python 2.6.6 here (scroll to bottom for the link to the patches): https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/issues/126